# reverse (left) arrow in an algorithm?

Tags: algorithms

There is a algorithm, in which author has written steps of algorithm like this,

1.initialization:set up the threshold (th) and maximum iteration number, $I$.

$i\leftarrow 0$

2.calculate x

while (x>th) do

$i\leftarrow i+1$

...

end while

what does this left arrow means here?

Comment: [Assignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_(computer_programming)).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It means "set", or assignment. So in most syntax, those lines are `i = 0` and `i = i + 1`. This was probably avoided because in math, $=$ means `==`, and assignment isn't a useful concept.

Comment: How does it differ from [`:=`](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25214/what-does-mean) then? I've seen both used in one algorithm.

Comment: Could be up to the author's personal choice of notation. I'm not personally aware of any well-established difference.