# Where would $\leftarrow$ fit in Wikipedia's list of maths symbols?

Tags: notation, definition

I read the symbol $\leftarrow$ in [this paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/454.pdf) in the last equation on p. 14 (or 15 out of 40).

$\text{Pr} \, [\,\textit{view} \leftarrow \textit{EXEC}^{\prod^{(V, C)}}...] $

Then I read [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/704942/503573), which confirmed that it is the assignment operator. Where would this fit in Wikipedia's list of math symbols by subject? Would it fit in [definition symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols_by_subject#Definition_symbols)?

I apologise if this is a bit off-topic, but if I post on the talk page, it might take longer to get an answer.

Comment: Yes, it is the [assignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_(computer_science)) operator. Often in programming it is used $:=$ that derives from "is equal to". In the context above, we can read as "is assigned to".

Comment: OK, I'll add the symbol to that section.

Comment: Actually I won't add it because I can't seem to find much use of that symbol in maths, although it is used as the [converse implication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Converse_implication). The context above of that symbol is assignment as in computing.

Comment: I added a row to [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols#Symbols_that_point_left_or_right) and [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols_by_subject#Operators).